# Creating a maven web project with tomcat server. The web.xml and index.jsp file are not opening up: It says Failed to create the part's controls

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm creating a maven web project with tomcat server. But the web.xml and index.jsp file are not opening up. Here's a screenshot of the error.

The error: Failed to create the part's controls -
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer [The image shows what I see after clicking on index.jsp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Ga4.png)

I have already tried re-starting workspace. Also, went to File Associations from preferences and set .jsp and java to deafualt. This was suggested in some other stackoverflow link.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I'm just learning everything. Can you pls tell me how to do that exactly?

Comment: If this isn't the current release, 2023-06, where this is solved, go get the current release.

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid way I said that , you need to check you imported the IBM jar containing that class into your project, and then compiled your project to a .war , then deploy to the Tomcat server in its "webapps" folder.

Comment: Note that Tomcat 9 and older versions servlet and framework API in the server use javax library name on imports but Tomcat 10 and newer use jakarta name in imports of classes, However, SE Core classes remain their actual naming for package imports into code.

Comment: Take a look at this "The Directory Structure of the WAR file"  https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/sample-web-application-war-file-download/      in the image it shows inside the "WEB-INF/classes" folder tree example the folder "com" , that folder is "typically" (a typical)  top folder name of the contents of a jar library that is added to a web project, of it is fine for all the jar files to use such a name or tree names the same , only .class file must be unique names when unloaded into use